# SQL Server: IsCharAlpha

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-server-2008, globalization

Is there a built-in, or workaround technique, to determine if a character "[IsAlpha](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)"?

---

i see a lot of suggestions that revolve around

```
IF PATINDEX('[a-zA-Z]', @c) > 0
BEGIN
   --It is alpha
END
```

Except that neglects alpha characters that are not in the given range `A-Z`.

Comment: What alpha characters are outside A-Z? Do you mean u with umlauts etc.? You can easily add any additional characters you want to count as alpha to the pattern match. Using a range will depend on collation, as different collations have different sort orders. There is nothing built-in, you'll have to define your own...

Comment: You mean characters like "â" are left out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collation controls how accents and diacritics are evaluated, such as whether or not `S` equals `Š`.

Note the results for the following... the first `SELECT` returns 2 matches, the second only returns 1 match:

```
DECLARE @testTable TABLE (testValue nvarchar(50))

insert into @testTable (testValue) values ('Š')
insert into @testTable (testValue) values ('S')
insert into @testTable (testValue) values ('4')

SELECT 'IsAlpha', testValue 
FROM @testTable 
WHERE PATINDEX('[a-zA-Z]', testValue COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) > 0 

SELECT 'IsAlpha', testValue 
FROM @testTable 
WHERE PATINDEX('[a-zA-Z]', testValue COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN) > 0
```

[You can find a list of collations within SQL Server 2008 and a brief descripition here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)